# Guiding user on two separate choices that begin with the same first step

Tags: website-design, usability

I am working on building a site which has two steps as the basis for the main functionality of the site:

- Asking a question
- Creating a new page

Before they can ask a question or create a new page they need to go through the process of locating the place on a map.

On the landing page how should I highlight the two options to avoid confusion?

I currently see three options:

---

*Option 1*

Click here to create a new page

Click here to ask a question

---

*Option 2*

Search for a location to begin creating a new page

Search for a location to begin asking a question

---

*Option 3*

Or would it be better to just have a single option like this:

*Search for a location to begin a new page or to ask a question*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 sounds good if the user's mental model have those two tasks clearly defined.

Option 3 would be better if the user wouldn't necessarily know for sure which they want to do.

Option 2 I wouldn't recommend .. the user doesn't need to a priori know the actual mechanics of the task to decide which option to choose - simply ask them for the location as step 1.